# Nuxtjs dynamic routes doesn't work on page reload after deploying as a SPA on AWS Amplify console

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, nuxt.js, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have deployed my Nuxtjs app as SPA on AWS using AWS Amplify console. Now my website has some dynamic routes which redirects to 404 page when reloaded or opened in a new tab. I know that when we generate a static site using `nuxt generate`  the routes should be using routes() in nuxt.config.js. But in SPA mode it should be working on page refresh or reload. Even in Angular when run in SPA mode dynamic routes work fine. Its so strange that the dynamic routes doesn't work when the website is run as a single page application.

When used locally in production mode i.e `npm run build && npm run start` the routes work fine.  But after deploying it to AWS Amplify it redirects to 404 page. What am I misssing here?
Here's the Amplify.yml config i used

```
version: 0.1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
test:
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: cypress
    configFilePath: '**/mochawesome.json'
    files:
      - '**/*.png'
      - '**/*.mp4'
  phases:
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote an article on how to deploy a Nuxt Application on Amplify [here](https://medium.com/@pascalluther/deploy-a-nuxt-spa-app-to-amazons-aws-amplify-74994d4326c1).

In a nutshell:

1. Go to App Settings -> Rewrites and redirects
2. Click on Edit and remove the existing rule
3. Add the following new rule:

**Source Address:**
`</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`

**Target Address:**
`/index.html`

**Type:**
`200 (Rewrite)`

Answer (score 1):

[@lupas](https://github.com/lupas) helped me in nuxt discord. You just need to set as below

1) On the Amplify console go to: Rewrites and redirects
2) Delete the existing entry
3) Add the following:
Source Address: 
Target address: /index.html
Type: 200 (Rewrite)

Comment: Could you please detail what you wrote in the source address please? I have the exact same issue with a dynamic route like `myWebsite.com/pending/243535`. I tried with `/pending/*` without success

Comment: In my case, same approach as @Pascal but just using `/pending/<*>` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything and the only thing that really worked was to set

```
ssr: false
```

in nuxt.confi.js, hope it works for any other person