# How to handle Expo linking on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, aws-amplify, react-native-web

I'm trying to publish my Expo Linking Configuration to my AWS Amplify project. My configuration works in localhost but doesn't work when I publish it. What am I doing wrong?

I have the following navigation code:

```js
export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={LinkingConfiguration}
      fallback={HomeContainer}
      theme={DefaultTheme}>
      <RootNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Linking configuration:

```js
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
import { Screens } from '../types/types'

export default {
  prefixes: [Linking.makeUrl('/')],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Root: {
        screens: /* screens routes */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the following build configuration for Amplify:

```
version: 1.0
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - nvm use 12
        - npm install --quiet --global expo-cli
        - >
          if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then
            yarn
          elif [ -f package-lock.json ] || [ -f npm-shrinkwrap.json ]; then
            npm ci
          else
            npm install
          fi
    build:
      commands:
        - ENV=production expo build:web
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: web-build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
      - $(npm root --global)/**/*
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved inspired by this question: [Nuxtjs dynamic routes doesn't work on page reload after deploying as a SPA on AWS Amplify console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60536751/nuxtjs-dynamic-routes-doesnt-work-on-page-reload-after-deploying-as-a-spa-on-aw)

Just added this redirect:
Source Address:
`</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`

Target Address:
`/index.html`

Type:
`200 (Rewrite)`